# Cannot add listeners to store in ExtJS Controller

Tags: extjs, controller, store

In my application I have a button in a toolbar. If I click on this button to open a window following code is executed:

```
[...]
onClick: function() {
    this.windowControl = this.getController('attributesearch.Window');
    this.windowControl.init();
    this.windowControl.showWindow();
}
[...]
```

This window contains some inputfields and a combobox with a store:

```
Ext.define('EM.store.AttributeQuery', {
    requires: ['EM.model.AttributeQuery'],
    model: 'EM.model.AttributeQuery',
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: './app/configuration/AttributeQueries.json',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'queries'
        }
    },
    autoLoad: true
});
```

Within the init method of my window controller I want to add one *onLoad-listener*
 I try to add this listener to the store:

```
init: function() {
        this.getAttributeQueryStore().on('load', this.onStoreLoad, this);
        this.control({
            'attributeSearchWindow': {
                afterrender: this.onWindowRendered
            }
        });
    },
```

The first line in the init method `this.getAttributeQueryStore().on('load', this.onStoreLoad, this);` produces the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'on' app/controller/attributesearch/Window.js:9.
```

It seems the store is not fully (or correct) instantiated. What am I missing?

**Edit:**

The console output for `this.getAttributeQueryStore()` is this:

```
constructor {self: function, superclass: Object, config: emptyFn, initConfigList: Array[0], initConfigMap: Object…}
__proto__: TemplateClass
$className: "EM.store.AttributeQuery"
autoLoad: true
config: emptyFn
configMap: TemplateClass
initConfigList: Array[0]
initConfigMap: Object
model: "EM.model.AttributeQuery"
proxy: Object
requires: Array[1]
self: function constructor() {
superclass: Object
__proto__: Object
}
```

Comment: check on console for `store`, probably `store` is not accessible

Comment: editet the response for console.log into my question. The store is something but seems not to be instantiated as I would expect (whatever it may be). I cannot find the method 'on' nor 'addListener' or any other method the ExtJS docs show to me.

Comment: try binding `store load ` event on window after render event

Comment: I get the same error if I try to add the listener within the afterrender event.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It is my own fault.

If you have a closer look at my store definition, you will see that i forgot to insert the `extent: 'Ext.store.Store'`. Thats it. Now i can add and remove listeners like i expected to.

Thank you everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just define the store's listener as part of the store's definition?

```
Ext.define('EM.store.AttributeQuery', {
    requires: ['EM.model.AttributeQuery'],
    model: 'EM.model.AttributeQuery',
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: './app/configuration/AttributeQueries.json',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'queries'
        }
    },
    autoLoad: true,
    listeners: {
       load: function(store, records, options) {
          EM.getApplication().getController('attributesearch.Window').onStoreLoad(store, records, options);
       }
    }
});
```

Comment: Hello Towler can you please share it's documentation. That would be nice of you. Thanks