# Unable to listen to load event in the controller

Tags: extjs, model-view-controller

I scanned many threads here at stackoverflow ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7193392/set-listener-for-store-events-in-a-controller) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18269060/cannot-add-listeners-to-store-in-extjs-controller)), but none of them helps me to solve my problem. So, I have a store which is defined like this:

```
Ext.define('fileseditor.store.fileseditorNavigStore',{
    extend:'Ext.data.TreeStore',
    ...
```

I've heard about getters and tried to do this in my controller:

```
init: function(){
    this.getfileseditorNavigStoreStore().addListener('load', this.finishedLoading, this);
```

But that results in an error `this.getfileseditorNavigStoreStore is not a function`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is done like this:

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.3/#!/api/Ext.app.Controller-cfg-stores

Write your own getter:

```
 Ext.define("MyApp.controller.Foo", {
     extend: "Ext.app.Controller",

     requires: [
         'MyApp.store.Users',
         'MyApp.store.Vehicles'
     ]

     getUsersStore: function() {
         return this.getStore("Users");
     },

     getVehiclesStore: function() {
         return this.getStore("Vehicles");
     }
 });
```

Or shorter

```
Ext.define("MyApp.controller.Foo", {
     extend: "Ext.app.Controller",
     stores: ['Users', 'Vehicles']
 });
```

*=> you can use de storeId, or fullName (fileseditor.store.fileseditorNavigStore)*

## update

Another way to listen for events in the controller is like this:

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.3/#!/api/Ext.app.Controller-method-listen

To listen to "load" events fired by Store with storeId="myStoreId":

```
 Ext.define('AM.controller.Users', {
     init: function() {
         this.listen({
             store: {
                 '#myStoreId': {
                     load: this.onMyStoreLoad
                 }
             }
         });
     },
     ...
 });
```

*Btw: By convention the top-level namespaces and the actual class names should be in CamelCased, everything else should be all lower-cased. so `FilesEditor.store.FilesEditorNaviagStore`*

Answer (score 1):

```
 var me = this;
 var filesEditorStore = Ext.create( 'fileseditor.store.fileseditorNavigStore' , {
        storeId : 'fileseditor'
    } );

  filesEditorStore.on( 'load' , function ( store , records , successful , eOpts ) {
        if ( successful ) { 
            me.finishedLoading();
        }
    } );
```